# Trouble joining my domain

Tags: windows-10, networking, active-directory, windows-domain, windows-server-2019

> An active Directory Domain Controller (AD DC) for the domain xyz.com could not be contacted.

i tride to solve this but nothing when i tried to join new computer to domain show massege that domain couldnt be found i check all thing dns the name of domain but still give me same massege notic : im new in this company and old I.T leaft the job

[image: pic for error]

Comment: Make sure the time is correct on both the host and the server. I have seen problems where this is a problem.

Comment: i check same thing thank you for answer me

Comment: Can you use a ethereal or wireshark and sniff the connection when you try to connect? I wonder if there's port clocking going on.